# Использование AsyncPipe в angular4

Tags: асинхронность, angular4

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите при использовании асинхронного пайпа (| async) в шаблоне с отображением данных будут ли добавляться автоматически данные в шаблон при добавлении их в бд ?

Comment: Конечно нет. `async pipe` используют чтоб не подписываться/отписываться от потока и чтоб не создавать отдельное свойство компонета для хранения данных от потока. Если вы хотите обновлять данных `real time`, то советую обратить внимание на использование `веб сокетов`.

Comment: А в чем сложность написать .suscribe() ? Только чтобы не подписываться ?

Comment: Вам надо использовать что то вроде firebase для этой задачи и как раз там есть официальная библиотека для angular!

Comment: у меня mysql просто